# Angular JS filters using Firebase data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have some data in firebase that looks like this:

```
|
|
--users
    |
    --1
      |
      --email:"hello@gmail.com"
      --name:"User 01"
    --2
      |
      --email:"hello2@gmail.com"
      --name:"User 02"
--chat
    |
    ---JU9ZpBj7P9dWgNYN4To
      |
      --email:"hello@gmail.com"
      --content:"Hi, i'm user 01! How are you?"
      --user:"1"
      --timestamp:"123456789"
    ---JX8ZpBnli7hliwehlfi
      |
      --email:"hello2@gmail.com"
      --content:"Hi, i'm user 02! I'm great thanks!"
      --user:"2"
      --timestamp:"123456789"
```

I get the chat data from firebase in an object called 'messages', and my HTML/angular looks like this:

```
<ul class="chat" ng-repeat="message in messages  | orderByPriority | reverse">
    <li>
        <strong>{{message.user | uid2name}}</strong> {{message.content}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

So what I want to do is grab message.user and convert it from a userid into a name. I figured a good way would be to use a filter:

```
.filter('uid2name', function(loginService, $rootScope) {

// Takes a userid and outputs a users name
return function(input) {
      var ref = new Firebase('https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com/users/' + input);
      return $firebase(ref).name;
};
})
```

Now this works fine, but it does so by essentially polling firebase multiple times per second - not what I want to do at all. I have thought about caching the response in $rootScope but this seems a bit sloppy. What's the best way going about this? I am open to any ideas, I am not wed to the idea of using a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are one the things I love a bout Angular, but they are too heavy (since they are evaluated with every digest cycle) and definitely does't suite to your approach, unless you use cache (just don't store it in $rootScope, create a cache service instead).

Firebase is all about performance, in most cases normalization is your enemy. You already store user email, why don't you also store user name as well?

Changing the data structure to include userId in the URL of your Chat data structure may help: [Data Modeling Best Practices in Firebase/AngularFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223690/data-modeling-best-practices-in-firebase-angularfire/25225375#25225375)

Comment: If I store the users name in each chat entry, what happens when their use changes their name? I want to be able to update the previous chat entries with name changes or other information. I'll check out the creating a cache service though.... Thanks :)

Comment: @NathanMoynihan Another way is to change your data structure, maybe this answer can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223690/data-modeling-best-practices-in-firebase-angularfire/25225375#25225375

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved this problem by using the [angular-cache](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-cache) plugin (the default angular cache-factory is good but it lacks a few useful features). I cached the users in order to use a filter without hammering firebase.